# Is there anyway to turn this into a loop to make it more inclusion?

Tags: c++

```
   if (player.is_alive() == true) {
    player_roll = roll();
   }
   if (ai1.is_alive() == true) {
    ai1_roll = roll();
   }
   if (ai2.is_alive() == true) {
    ai2_roll = roll();
   }
   if (ai3.is_alive() == true) {
    ai3_roll = roll();
   }
   if (ai4.is_alive() == true) {
    ai4_roll = roll();
   }
   if (ai5.is_alive() == true) {
    ai5_roll = roll();
   }
```

This is checking if the player and ai(they are objects) is alive and the allowing them to roll(which is a random function)

Comment: Whenever you start naming things like `ai1`, `ai2`, etc.: the array (or `std::vector`) seems like a natural choice. And, you can, easily, loop over it.

Comment: `for(auto & a :{player, ai1 /*...*/})` should do the trick if they are of the same type. If they only have a common base class, take pointers to the objects.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `if(player.is_alive() == true)` is usually written `if(player.is_alive())`.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the alive test and roll into a function, for example:

```
void IfAliveRoll(Player& player, uint32_t& roll)
{
    if (player.is_alive())
        roll = roll();
}
```

You can then simply use this for as many entities are you want:

```
IfAliveRoll(player, player_roll);
IfAliveRoll(ai1, ai1_roll);
IfAliveRoll(ai2, ai2_roll);
IfAliveRoll(ai3, ai3_roll);
IfAliveRoll(ai4, ai4_roll);
IfAliveRoll(ai5, ai5_roll);
```

The function name makes it very clear what is happening.

Comment: If this specific function is only used that this place, one could also declare it as a local lambda.